# How is possible consume my custom Theme with useTheme() hook?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I have a piece of code when I declare my MuiProvider, like this:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={merge(defaultGlobalTheme, this.props.adjustThemeOptions)}>
    {this.props.children}
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

How could I consume my custom theme (declared in MuiThemeProvider with @material-ui/core@3.9.3 library) with Material-UI Hooks (declared in @material-ui/styles@3.0.0-alpha.10) or with another solution with Hooks?

EDIT:
You can consume with this way:

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/styles';

function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <div>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</div>;
}
```

**BUT** my solution works **IF** you have components with @material-ui/core in the above version and you are using the @material-ui/styles library.

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Fran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

customTheme didn't work with useTheme() because of I was using a ThemeProvider from @material-ui/core@3.9.3 and it wasn't compatible with useTheme() from @material-ui/styles@^3.0.0-alpha.10.

Solution is explained by the guys from Material-UI in [this link](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#migration-for-material-ui-core-users)

Basically, you have to add at the top when no Material-UI has been imported yet these lines:

```
import { install } from '@material-ui/styles';

install();
```

And ThemeProvider and the rest of components will be compatible for the components of the library @material-ui/styles

PD: It's temporary because hooks aren't yet in @material/core but they will be in v4

Thank you for the help!

Best,
Fran.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hook to consume the context supplied by the `MuiThemeProvider`, but if you can use the [`ThemeProvider`](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/api/#themeprovider) instead you can use the [`useTheme`](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/api/#usetheme-theme) hook to consume the theme in a component that is below the provider in the tree.

```
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/styles';

function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <div>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I've declared a custom theme with a new attribute "palette" for example, and when I try to use it in a style rule an error is released with the following message: "The properties palette is undefined".

Comment: @fg93 I might be wrong in my answer. [It works with a regular `ThemeProvider` at least](https://codesandbox.io/s/ppynyv51mq). Maybe that's not what you need?

Comment: Yes, I need that but... I think I've already found the problem. I think I was importing ThemeProvider from @material-ui/core/MuiThemeProvider and I need the same but from @material-ui/styles/ThemeProvider and call the install() method from @material-ui/styles.